# Swarm offline method don't work (using AndEngine)

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have tried several times, but the Swarm don't work for offline...
In the site, he say "put this file in your Android project's assets", it is JSON file. I have put it in my assets folder, but it don't work.
Maybe he's not reading this file.

LogCat error:

```
04-25 02:42:48.621: W/System.err(12466): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.swarmconnect.com": No address associated with hostname
04-25 02:42:48.621: W/System.err(12466):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
04-25 02:42:48.640: W/System.err(12466):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
04-25 02:42:48.640: W/System.err(12466):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-25 02:42:48.644: W/System.err(12466):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
```

When the HomeScreen are show:

```
@Override
    public void createScene() {
        if ( Swarm.isEnabled() ) {
            Swarm.init(this.activity, GameConfig.SWARP_APP_ID, GameConfig.SWARP_APP_KEY);
        }
        createBackground();
        createMenuChildScene();
    }
```

On play menu clicked:

```
public boolean onMenuItemClicked(MenuScene pMenuScene, IMenuItem pMenuItem, float pMenuItemLocalX, float pMenuItemLocalY)
    {
        switch(pMenuItem.getID()) {
            case MENU_PLAY:
                if (! Swarm.isInitialized() ) {
                    Swarm.init(this.activity, GameConfig.SWARP_APP_ID, GameConfig.SWARP_APP_KEY, mySwarmLoginListener);
                }else{
                    SceneManager.getInstance().loadGameScene(engine);
                }
//many switch code where...
```

SwarmListener:

```
private SwarmLoginListener mySwarmLoginListener = new SwarmLoginListener() {

        // This method is called when the user has successfully logged in.
        public void userLoggedIn(SwarmActiveUser user) {
            //Carrega Game Scene
            SceneManager.getInstance().loadGameScene(engine);
        }

        public void userLoggedOut() {  }
        public void loginStarted() { }
        public void loginCanceled() { }
    };

}
```

Swarm working great online...

Yeah, I tried to contact support, never answered me.